# MSCK Command Throwing Error When Google Storage Set As Location In Properties

Tags: hadoop, hive, google-cloud-storage

I have a external partitioned hive table whose Location is set as 'gs://xxxx'.I have added some partitions manually and for regestering that partitions to hive metastore , i ran MSCK REPAIR command which throws following error:

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from 
>      org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask

Please let me know why this error getting generated

Comment: Which version of hive are you using ?
There seems to be one bug .. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-14798
Can you try a work around :- ( For static partition as you mentioned you added manually )
set hive.msck.path.validation=ignore;
MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name;

Comment: its 2.1.0 hive version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
set hive.msck.path.validation=ignore; MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name;
```

If it doesn't work check the DDL and the Partition fields. Keep in mind only Int and String is supported as partition values

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to run Alter Table and set location to a subdirectory in gcs as given below.

`ALTER TABLE TABLENAME SET LOCATION gs://crazybucketstring/schemname/tableaname/`

If you are interested to understand why it is giving error with `msck repair` read this answer [Drop Hive Table & msck repair fails with Table stored in google cloud bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63146214/drop-hive-table-msck-repair-fails-with-table-stored-in-google-cloud-bucket)

This problem is related to gs location of your table.
Even though msck repair with ignored path validation as given in other answer works but it fails to solve underlying issue.