# Drop Hive Table & msck repair fails with Table stored in google cloud bucket

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-platform, hive, google-cloud-storage

I am creating hive table in Google Cloud Bucket using below SQL statement.

```sql
CREATE TABLE schema_name.table_name (column1 decimal(10,0), column2 int, column3 date) 
   PARTITIONED BY(column7 date) STORED AS ORC
   LOCATION 'gs://crazybucketstring/' 
   TBLPROPERTIES('ORC.COMPRESS'='SNAPPY');
```

Then I loaded data into this table using `distcp` command, Now when I try to Drop table it fails with below error message, Even if I try to drop empty table it fails.

```sql
hive>>DROP TABLE schema_name.table_name; 

**Error:** Error while processing statement: 
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.MetaException
(message:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: `hadoopPath must not be null`)
(state=08S01,code=1)
```

I also removed files from Google Cloud Storage bucket using `gsutil rm -r gs://` command but still not able to delete table and giving same error

Also on running `msck repair table` it is giving following error.

```
FAILED: 
Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask (state=08S01,code=1)
```

Any Idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Looks like there is a typo with a missing closing single quote on the `LOCATION` line.

Comment: yes that is typo.

Comment: i guess your bucket directory ends here `gs://j348247g25f61ab3yta9d59c35k5626020746fad383b7d6a6e36ra935ca7ec/` due to `TBLPROPERTIES` its a property from Hive.

Comment: can you try `DROP TABLE  table_name PURGE; `. I have seen sometime purge does the trick. I know no purge sends data to trash but still give it a try.

Comment: @KoushikRoy I tried purge too. Not working. In fact I created more similar tables but facing same issue. Even after entire bucket is blank after gsutil rm command.

Comment: Can you try creating a table without mentioning LOCATION and then drop it? i think its creating external table when you provide location parameter and somehow its not able to drop it.  Also, hope you have drop access on that database.

Comment: Yes that will work, but my requirement is to create table in designated bucket. Also it is Managed Table. Also I deleted all files from bucket still no benefit. still checking with colleagues, will update if I find any solution.

Comment: This means hive user can create/drop tables created by itself. Normally i have seen, the locations are managed by hive internal users. So, can your admin create a location and grant RWX permission to your user and see if you can create/drop that table. But i am skeptical since the create table is done by hive user and same user cant drop it. Better connect the admin and showing them the error and ask them the root cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to bucket location. I will try to explain it in step by step manner on how to recreate it and how to solve it. this same issue also result in unable to run `msck repair` command.

**How to Recreate it:**

1. First I created a table (T1) with location pointing to the bucket given here:
   `LOCATION 'gs://crazybucketstring/'`
2. Then I created another table (T2) in-side bucket in subfolder with location as given
   below
   `LOCATION gs://crazybucketstring/schemname/tableaname/`
3. Now when I try to drop first table (T1) it throws error as entire
   bucket is behaving as table and it can't delete bucket, it can just
   delete files.
4. When I try to drop table (T2) I am able to drop it and also files inside bucket subdirectory is deleted as it is managed table. Table T1 is still a headache.

In a desperate bid to delete Table T1, I emptied the bucket using `gsutil rm -r` command and tried `msck repair table tablename` and strangely `msck repair` command failed with below error message

```
>>  msck repair table tablename
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: 
Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask (state=08S01,code=1)
```

As usual DROP command was still not working.

**Solution:**

Eventually I got this Idea which worked.

1. I Altered Table T1 and SET its location to subdirectory inside bucket instead of bare bucket.
   `ALTER TABLE TABLENAME SET LOCATION gs://crazybucketstring/schemname/tableaname/`
2. Now I do 'msck repair' and it doesn't throw any error.
3. I issued DROP Table command and it worked.

> This issue is related to Table Location which we should deal with
> carefully while creating more than 1 Table in same bucket. Best
> practice is to use different subdirectories inside bucket to create
> different tables and avoid using just bucket path as table location specially if you have to create multiple tables in same bucket. Thank you and feel free to reach out to [Me](https://www.linkedin.com/in/sanjeetshukla/) for Big Data issues.